Why cant I see any transactions at the Grafana dashboard dropdwon
I have add transaction controllers to my jmeter test. But still I cant see any transactions at the Grafana dashboard.
Here is the defenition for the transaction variable at Grafana :
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "jmeter" WITH KEY = "transaction" WHERE "application" =~ /^$application$/ AND "transaction" != 'internal' AND "transaction" != 'all'




I was able to fix this by having highlighted properties at j meter

